# Trying to add the currency symbol to value using system.globalization

Tags: c#, .net, double, globalization, mschart

i am trying to add the currency symbol to totalvalue by using following code

```cs
using System.Globalization;

double value;
double totalValue = 0.0;            

foreach (DataRow row in reportData.Rows)
{
    if (double.TryParse(row["value"].ToString(), out value))
    {
        totalValue += value;
        RegionInfo rgi = new RegionInfo("en-UK");
        totalValue += Convert.ToString(string.Format("   CurrencySymbol:               {0}\n", rgi.CurrencySymbol));             
     }
 }
```

it was giving error can not convert type `string` to `double` 
would any one pls help me

Modified CODE:

```
       int count;
      int total = 0;
      double value;

      double totalValue = 0.0;




      foreach (DataRow row in reportData.Rows)
      {
        if (double.TryParse(row["value"].ToString(), out value))
        {
          totalValue += value;


        }

        if (!Overview && int.TryParse(row["mshipssold"].ToString(), out count))
        {
          total += count;
        }
      }
      DataRow totalRow = reportData.NewRow();
      totalRow["mshipType_Name"] = "Total";
      totalRow["mshipssold"] = total;
      totalRow["value"] = totalValue;

      reportData.Rows.Add(totalRow);

      targetChartControl.Series["Value"].Points.DataBindXY(reportData.Rows, "mshipType_Name", reportData.Rows, "value");

      if (!Overview)
      {
        targetChartControl.Series["Quantity"].Points.DataBindXY(reportData.Rows, "mshipType_Name", reportData.Rows, "mshipssold");
      }
    }
```

Modified code :1

graph[image]

I want to show  like this  £3830 , £2070 , £5090 on the blue bars

and this is my code

```
   try
    {
    DataTable reportData = KPIData.MembershipSales(StartDate, EndDate, mf);
    Series quantitySeries;
    Series valueSeries = null;
    Title title;
    string area;

    targetChartControl.ChartAreas.Clear();
    targetChartControl.Series.Clear();
    targetChartControl.Titles.Clear();

    area = "Value";
    targetChartControl.ChartAreas.Add(area);
    quantitySeries = targetChartControl.Series.Add(area);
    quantitySeries.ChartArea = area;

    if (!Overview)
    {
      title = targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Membership Sales by Total Contract Value by Type");
      title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
      title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
      title.DockedToChartArea = area;

      targetChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;
    }

    targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Membership sale values").DockedToChartArea = area;


    if (!Overview)
    {
      area = "Quantity";
      targetChartControl.ChartAreas.Add(area);
      quantitySeries = targetChartControl.Series.Add(area);
      quantitySeries.ChartArea = area;

      title = targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Membership Sales by Quantity");
      title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
      title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
      title.DockedToChartArea = area;

      targetChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;
      targetChartControl.Titles.Add("Membership sale quantities").DockedToChartArea = area;
    }

    foreach (Title chartTitle in targetChartControl.Titles)
    {
      chartTitle.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
    }

    foreach (ChartArea chartArea in targetChartControl.ChartAreas)
    {
      chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
      chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
    }

    foreach (Series series in targetChartControl.Series)
    {
      series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
      series["ColumnDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
      series["LabelStyle"] = "Top";

      series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
      //          series.CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=Cylinder";
      series.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
    }

    foreach (Legend legend in targetChartControl.Legends)
    {
      legend.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (reportData == null)
    {
      valueSeries.Points.Clear();
      valueSeries.Points.AddXY("No sales for this time period", 0);

      if (!Overview)
      {
        quantitySeries.Points.Clear();
        quantitySeries.Points.AddXY("No sales for this time period", 0);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      int count;
      int total = 0;
      double value;

      double totalValue = 0.0;




      foreach (DataRow row in reportData.Rows)
      {
        if (double.TryParse(row["value"].ToString(), out value))
        {
          totalValue += value;    

        }

        if (!Overview && int.TryParse(row["mshipssold"].ToString(), out count))
        {
          total += count;
        }
      }

      CultureInfo rgi = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
      string totalcurrency = string.Format(rgi, "{0:C}", totalValue);

      DataRow totalRow = reportData.NewRow();
      totalRow["mshipType_Name"] = "Total";
      totalRow["mshipssold"] = total;
      totalRow["value"] = totalcurrency;

      reportData.Rows.Add(totalRow);

      targetChartControl.Series["Value"].Points.DataBindXY(reportData.Rows, "mshipType_Name", reportData.Rows, "value");

      if (!Overview)
      {
        targetChartControl.Series["Quantity"].Points.DataBindXY(reportData.Rows, "mshipType_Name", reportData.Rows, "mshipssold");
      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
  }
```

Comment: I believe you are displaying a chart and want the symbol to appear on them ? if so you should try setting up the format in the chart control like `Format='C'` for Y axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do your totalling and then convert it to a string.

```
double totalValue;
foreach (DataRow row in reportData.Rows) {
  double value;
  if (double.TryParse(row["value"].ToString(),out value) totalValue+= value;
}
CultureInfo rgi = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
string totalValueCurrency=string.Format(rgi,"{0:c}", totalValue);
```

In answer to your modified question:

before before `DataRow totalRow = reportData.NewRow();` insert the two lines

```
CultureInfo rgi = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
string totalValueCurrency=string.Format(rgi,"{0:c}", totalValue);
```

and then change

```
totalRow["value"] = totalValue;
```

to read

```
totalRow["value"] = totalValueCurrency;
```

However this might go horribly wrong if the datatype of your column is not string. You may be better of changing your report to do the formatting for you.

If you are using Microsoft Chart Control you may want this instead:

Modify this section of code

```
foreach (ChartArea chartArea in targetChartControl.ChartAreas)    {
  chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
  chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
  // New Line Here
  chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "C";
}
```

Comment: where you add the symbol to total value

Comment: I don't I put it into totalValueCurrency, Doubles cannot hold the currency symbol, only strings can, so I run your totalling algorithm and then save the result into a string variable

Comment: would you look at my modified code where i have to add the symbol and i need to show the symbol in report ....... i am bit confusing .....pls help me .....

Comment: @ Bob vale   ok i am confusing for this there is no relation between totalvalue and totalvaluecurrency. is these two are same or different and i want to  add the currency symbol to value and total value is it possible

Comment: @user682417 - DOH! I hadn't properly read your format string and assumed you where formatting totalValue yourself.  I've now corrected the answer

Comment: finally it was not showing the symbol in report......   CultureInfo rgi = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
          string totalcurrency = string.Format(rgi, "{0:C}", totalValue);                                               totalRow["value"] = totalcurrency; this is what i have added

Comment: That will only add the symbol to the total row, this answers your question, however I think the real solution you are looking for means you need to tell the report itself to format the values instead of doing it in the code behind.  What report are you using?

Comment: the report is done by mschart i will place the code and graph also pls see look at my modified code:1

Comment: would you pls take a look at Modified Code:1

Comment: Did you not look at the final lines of my answer?

Comment: It was showing the symbols on y axis like this £0 ,£5000 , £1000 but this is not what i want ........ i want to show the symbols on gold mem..bars and silvermem... and total bars..  like this  ...            £3830 , £2070 , £5900 like this I want ..

Comment: Finally I got by using this formula     series.LabelFormat = "C";  thanq

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a string in a double - this will never work when totalValue is a double.

> totalValue += Convert.ToString(string.Format("   CurrencySymbol:               {0}\n", rgi.CurrencySymbol));

Answer (score 0):

This line is a bit confused:

```
          totalValue += Convert.ToString(string.Format("   CurrencySymbol:               {0}\n", rgi.CurrencySymbol));
```

`totalValue` is a double and you're trying to add a string to it.